# How can I calculate all of the possible combinations of two 1x6 vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, combinations

I have two 1x6 vectors that I am eventually trying to just sum up, but I need to get all of the possible combinations of these vectors before doing so. The vectors will look like so:

```
V1=[a b c d e f];
V2=[A B C D E F];
```

What I need is to find all possible combinations of variables that will remain a 1x6 vector. I have been messing around for a while now and I think I have found a way by using various matrices but it seems terribly inefficient. An example of what I am looking for is as follows.

```
 M=[a b c d e f;
    A b c d e f;
    A B c d e f; 
    A B C d e f; 
    A B C D e f; 
    A B C D E f; 
    A B C D E F;
           . . .]
```

And so on and so forth until all combinations are found. Unfortunately I am not a MATLAB whiz hence the reason I'm reaching out. I'm sure there has to be a much simpler way than what I have been trying. I hope that my question was relatively clear. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used `cellfun` to create the indexes:

```
V1=['abcdef'];
V2=['ABCDEF'];
VV = [V1;V2];
l = length(V1);
pows = 0:l-1;
x = num2cell(2.^pows);
L = x{end};
rows = cellfun(@(x) reshape([ones(x,L/x);2*ones(x,L/x)],[2*L 1]),x,'Uniformoutput',0);
rows = cell2mat(rows);
cols = repmat(1:l,[2*L 1]);
idxs = sub2ind(size(VV),rows,cols);
M = VV(idxs);
```

and you get:

```
M = 
    abcdef
    Abcdef
    aBcdef
    ABcdef
    abCdef
    AbCdef
    aBCdef
    ABCdef
    abcDef
    AbcDef
    ...
```